# Get the ID for an element when in status MouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with event `onMouseOver`. I need to get the ID for the element when the event is fired.

Here my HTML structure:

```
'<div id="see_all" class="btn_backtostart_catview">' + 
    '<div class="btn_backtostart_slice_l_catview"></div>' +
    '<div class="btn_backtostart_slice_c_catview" onclick="Main.magicCtrVerTodas()" onMouseOver="Main.magicCtrVerTodasMouseOver(this)">Ver todas</div>' +
    '<div class="btn_backtostart_slice_r_catview"></div>' +
'</div>' +
```

The function

```
magicCtrVerTodasMouseOver: function(obj){        
    console.log('ID for elm in OVER: ' + obj);
},
```

As result I get `HTMLDivElement` no the name of the ID.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I also can use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `obj` is referred to `<div>` element with class `"btn_backtostart_slice_c_catview"`. This element doesn't have an ID attribute.

If you need to get the `id` property of the parent `<div>` (holding `id="see_all"`), you may use:

```
magicCtrVerTodasMouseOver: function(obj){
    console.log('ID for elm in OVER: ' + obj.parentNode.id);
}
```

Comment: Great! This solved the problem, may I ask how to do the same also with jquery?

Comment: @GibboK As easy as: `$(obj).parent().prop("id")`. However, the pure JavaScript solution will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
magicCtrVerTodasMouseOver: function(obj){
    console.log('ID for elm in OVER: ' + obj.id);
},
```

However, make sure that the element has an `id`.